# InstallData not working on Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, setup, installdata

I have an **InstallData** script below which works absolutely fine on **Magento 2.2** but failed to install data on **Magento 2.1**

```
class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{   
public function install(
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
) {    
    $contextInstall = $context;
    $contextInstall->getVersion();        
    $data = [];
    $statuses = [
        'data_one' => __('Data One'),
        'data_two' => __('Data Two'),
        'data_three' => __('Data Three'),                                   
    ];
    foreach ($statuses as $code => $info) {
        $data[] = ['status' => $code, 'label' => $info];
    }
     if (!$setup->tableExists('table_name')) {
    $setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable('table_name'), ['db_colum_one', 'db_column_two'], $data);
     }

}
}
```

Can anyone help , if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your if condition.

```
if (!$setup->tableExists('table_name')) {
```

Your condition is checking if the **table don't exits** then run the query. if the table is created then it will not executed.I think that what happened. 
You solution will be change if the collection is empty then add records.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute `InstallData.php`, You must need to remove your module entry from `setup_module` table than execute

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Hope it will help you. !!

Comment: already done with setup:upgrade, but no data installed

Comment: Did you remove your module from table which i mention in answer !?

Comment: yes! removed the module entry

Comment: What's error you are getting in CLI ?

Comment: No errors ! setup:upgrade is successfull

Comment: Check here. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/

Comment: put echo and exit in your `InstallData.php` and check but after removing entry from `setup_module` @Verdu

Comment: @KeyurShah I Just remvoed the if (!$setup->tableExists('table_name')) {} conditions and it worked. But I need to place the condition . Why it is not working on 2.1??

Comment: So in that case table must exist in your database try to remove that table(if it does not contain any data) and check @Verdu